# Docker build problems with pip install -r requirements: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

Tags: python, docker, pip

I'm trying to Docker build a django app, but I get te following message when docker tries to pip install -r requirements:

```
Collecting Django==2.2.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1) WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7ff789506828>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/django/
```

There's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

My Linux distro:

```
Linux version 4.15.0-30deepin-generic (pbuilder@zs-PC) (gcc version 6.3.0 20170516 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1)) #31 SMP Fri Nov 30 04:29:02 UTC 2018
```

Not only Django, but all requirements cannot be installed. I'm not using a Proxy

Comment: How about if you do `pip install` directly, not from a `requirements` file?

Comment: same error with RUN pip install Django==2.2.5 in place of RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

Comment: btw, tried RUN pip install --upgrade pip and get this error: WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fd8f8d657b8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/pip/

Comment: Does your host environment have a working network connection? Can you `pip install` from your host environment?

Comment: Yes, I have connection in my host. I can pip install and pip install -r requirements in terminal. Looks like I don't have network/connection inside the docker container

Answer (score 24):

Could be a lack of network access during the build. Try:

```
docker build --network=host .
```

Comment: This solved my issue which was caused by running `docker system prune -a --volumes`

Comment: worked in Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, in my case, I was connected to a VPN server, disconnecting from the VPN client resolved the issue.

Comment: that was the case for me as well. and disconnecting from VPN fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

I am on Mac OS. In my case, `--network=host` doesn't work.

The issue was caused by using a class-A address as DNS server address.

https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#dns-services

The error message is like

```
#7 10.71 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f278078d8b0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/xxxxxxx/
```

Mac OS does not have docker daemon. My solution on Mac OS is to configure the DNS address in docker desktop.

1. Open Docker Desktop
2. Click the setting at top-right
3. Docker Engine
4. Add `"8.8.8.8"` as the first element in the `"dns"` array.
5. Restart docker desktop

Comment: Thanks, this had me pulling my hair out for half a day.